# Getting values from another worksheet through loops in python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

What I'm trying to do is getting each column in Source worksheet and pasting them to Target_sheet in another worksheet, each pasting action should start from the third row though (Ex: A3:A, B3:B ...)

However I get error such as:

```
 ata.values[1731]","description": "Invalid value at 'data.values[1731]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), \"x23232x2x2x442x42x42x42\""
              },
              {
                "field": "data.values[1732]",
                "description": "Invalid value at 'data.values[1732]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), \"x242x42x42x42x42x442x427\""
              },
              {
                "field": "data.values[1733]",
                "description": "Invalid value at 'data.values[1733]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), \"x42x424242x42454555x56666\""
              }
                                                       .
                                                       .
                                                       .
```

My code:

```
sh = client.open('Target')

sh.values_clear("Target_sheet!A3:J10000")

source = client.open('Source')
source_col_numbers = source.sheet1.col_count

i = 1

# creating a holder for the values in Source.sheet1
columns = {}

#getting the values in each column at the Source.sheet1
while i <= source_col_numbers:
    columns[i] = list(filter(None , source.sheet1.col_values(i)))
    i += 1

# will use this variable to iterate between columns in the Target.Target_sheet
charn=ord("A")


#updating the columns in the Target with values from Source

b=1

while b <= source_col_numbers:

    sh.values_update(
        "Target_sheet!"+chr(charn)+"3:"+chr(charn)
         ,
         params={
            'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'
         } ,
         body={
           'values': columns[b]
        }
        )
    charn+=1
    b+=1
```

@carlesgg97 tried with get_value but still getting error I mentioned under your comment:

```
target_worksheet.values_clear("Target!A3:J10000") 

source = client.open('Source') 

source_col_numbers = source.sheet1.col_count 

source_values=source.values_get('Sheet1!A:J') 

last_column=chr(source_col_numbers) 

target_worksheet.values_update( 
"Target!A3:"+last_column , 
params={ 'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED' }, 
body={ 'values': source_values } 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `col_values` you obtain the values of the column, in a list. However, when using the `values_update` method, the body requires the "values" property to be a list of lists (see: [col_values](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)).

Further to that, I believe the task you are attempting to accomplish can be done in a much more simpler way, using [`values_get`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_get). An example that would move the range `A1:J9997` to `A4:J10000` (moved 3 rows down) would look as follows:

```js
sh = client.open('Target')

sh.values_clear("Target_sheet!A3:J10000")

response = sh.values_get("A1:J9997")

spreadsheet.values_update(
    'Target_sheet!A3:J10000',
    params = {
        'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED'
    },
    body = {
        'values': response['values']
    }
)
```

Comment: hey thanks, please find the code that I tried values_get in the main post body above but getting the error below: spread.exceptions.APIError: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"range\" at 'data.values': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name

Comment: Hey @zeppelin11, thanks for the feedback. When sending the `values_update()` request, the body should be `{ 'values': source_values['values'] }` (notice the usage of the `[ ]` operator to retrieve the actual values). Let me know if that works for you. Cheers